# Django get the name of column in the query set

Tags: django, python-2.7, mongoengine

I am using Django REST framework along with Mongoengine for Mongo db. My question is, how can I get the column name in the query set I m iterating over? I want the column name to built the output JSON.

Comment: Can you put a lil' bit of code (serializer, model..)?

Answer (score 0):

`MongoEngine` `BaseQuerySet` contains `_document` field with your document class. `Document` contains `_fields` field with dictionary where keys is fields names. `Document` also contains interesting field `_fields_ordered` with ordered fields names.

```
def get_tuple_of_fileds(query_set):
    #return tuple(query_set._document._fields.keys())
    return query_set._document._fields_ordered
```

But do not forget that any document from `QuerySet` already have all fields and have interesting methods like `to_json` (`bson` style). `BaseQuerySet` also contains `to_json` method.